# WordPress query single post by slug

Tags: php, wordpress

For the moment when I want to show a single post without using a loop I use this:

```
<?php
$post_id = 54;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
echo $queried_post->post_title; ?>
```

The problem is that when I move the site, the id's usually change.
Is there a way to query this post by slug?

Comment: Why would the IDs change when moving the site?  Unless you are moving the site by using WP's import/export feature (which isn't terribly reliable and I would recommend avoiding).  If you are simply migrating the database nothing will change.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

From the WordPress Codex:

```
<?php
$the_slug = 'my_slug';
$args = array(
  'name'           => $the_slug,
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
if( $my_posts ) :
  echo 'ID on the first post found ' . $my_posts[0]->ID;
endif;
?>
```

[WordPress Developper Resources Get Posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)

Comment: This shows the ID - $my_posts[0]->ID; - but how do I display the pages content? I've tried everything and nothing works!

Comment: @JamesWilson start using kint. `echo $my_posts[0]->post_content`

Comment: This seems to return multiple, and thus ambiguous, results if some slugs are quite similar (e.g. 'work' vs 'working')

Comment: Not sure why but I had to change 'name' to 'post_name' for this query to work for me

Comment: This works to get the featured image $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($my_posts[0]->ID) );

Comment: Not working for me, not with 'name' or with 'post_name' or with 'post_title', it just ignores it and fetches any posts

Comment: It's important to note that post_type does not default to 'any' here as one would expect - it instead defaults to 'post'.  And post_status does not default to 'any' here either; it defaults to 'publish', so you can't omit these two parameters unless you are looking specifically for published posts and not pages or attachments or drafts.

Comment: It's not working for me. Looks like WP updaed this function logic and there is no available 'name' property.

Answer (score 85):

How about?

```
<?php
   $queried_post = get_page_by_path('my_slug',OBJECT,'post');
?>
```

Comment: Pay attention to children pages or hierarchical custom post types: `my-slug` should become `my-parent-slug/my-slug`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path#Examples

Comment: my experience since reading this post supports @Erenor Paz -- it may indeed be pretty and simple but it becomes complex when you depend on consistency of the slug -- which can change simply by changing the parent post... *sigh* -- perhaps we could convince WordPress devs to to allow wildcard in the path, example: get_page_by_path( '*/my_slug' );

Comment: Not very reliable

Answer (score 11):

a less expensive and reusable method

```
function get_post_id_by_name( $post_name, $post_type = 'post' )
{
    $post_ids = get_posts(array
    (
        'post_name'   => $post_name,
        'post_type'   => $post_type,
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ));

    return array_shift( $post_ids );
}
```

Comment: Nice method, but I think 

`'post_name'   => $post_name,`

should be

`'name'   => $post_name,`

Answer (score 8):

As wordpress api has changed, you can´t use get_posts with param 'post_name'. I´ve modified Maartens function a bit:

```
function get_post_id_by_slug( $slug, $post_type = "post" ) {
    $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'name'   => $slug,
            'post_type'   => $post_type,
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'fields'      => 'ids',
        ) );
    $posts = $query->get_posts();
    return array_shift( $posts );
}
```

Comment: For additional performance I'd also add `'no_found_rows' => true` to the get_posts arguments.

Comment: there is no need to instantiate a new `WP_Query` and it's not "best practice"... just feed your array to `get_posts`... `$posts = get_posts( *your array* );` -- (this is an old thread but perhaps my comment will be useful to someone)

Comment: @aequalsb your comment is wrong: `get_posts()` is a wrapper around a `new WP_Query` statement. You actually need to instantiate a new WP_Query object to process that query

Comment: @Philipp not wrong... what i said is "there is no need to instantiate a new WP_Query"... you can simply call `get_posts()`... simpler... less lines of code.. and it also avoids having to call `wp_reset_postdata()` afterwards.. which is omitted from the suggested answer...

Comment: Should be 'nice_name'   => $slug,

Answer (score 1):

This can

**Fetch multiple posts regardless of post type** by slug(s).

```php
function get_posts_by_slugs($slugs) {
    global $wpdb;
    $slugs = !is_array($slugs) ? [$slugs] : $slugs;
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE `post_name` IN ('" . implode("', '", $slugs) . "')" );
    return $posts;
}

$post = get_posts_by_slugs( 'hello-world' ); // fetches single post

$posts = get_posts_by_slugs( ['hello-world', 'post-2-slug'] ); // fetches multiple post
```

Reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Comment: its the only thing that worked for me with custom post type and a messed up site, great answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$page = get_page_by_path('slug', ARRAY_N);
echo $page->post_content

function get_id_by_slug($page_slug) {
      $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug, ARRAY_N);
      if ($page[0] > 0) {
        return $page[0];
      }else{
        return null;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future Googlers - none of the above methods worked for me in **Wordpress 6.2.2**.

Eventualy I've found the **`url_to_postid()`** function, which solved my problem - it returns the correct post ID.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/