# Wordpress query_posts with ID and slug combination

Tags: wordpress

is it possible to use query_posts with a combination of id's and slugs?

I have an array of id's and slugs from user input and want to know if I can use the two in the same post query, or do I have to convert the slugs into their respective post ID's before and then use posts__in?

I have the following mixture of slugs and ID's in an array…

```
$values = array('this-is-a-test-slug', '2345', '4510', 'another-slug-here', '8934');
```

How can I use this in query_posts? Can I at all?

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'post__in' => $values, 'orderby' => 'rand'));
```

I know that post__in works ok with numeric ID's but I don't think slugs work here as it expects a numerical array.

Thanks

Comment: without code it's hard to see precisely what you mean. That being said, maybe **if(is_numeric($key)){// Its an ID} else {//chances are it's a slug}**

Comment: Hi @dwhite.me - I didn't post any code as I thought it was a general question but will amend the original post to help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing something like this, i don't see why it wouldn't be a problem to just convert them all over to ID? [There's a thread that sort of helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979837/wordpress-query-single-post-by-slug), and I've written some code (with help from that link) that might help you get started

```
function allToID($array){
  $id = array(); 

  foreach($array as $convert):
      if(is_numeric($convert)):
          continue; // skip if it's already an ID
      else:

        $the_slug = $convert;
        $args=array(
          'name' => $the_slug,
          'numberposts' => 1
        );

        // Ask wordpress to get this post
        $my_posts = get_posts($args);

        if( $my_posts ) : 
            // push onto our new array of only IDs
            array_push($id, $my_posts[0]->ID);
        else continue; 
        endif;
    endif;
  endforeach;
}
```

Ideally you'll be able to run `post__in => alltoID($values)`

Hope this helps!